# Golang goroutines in loop

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a question about goroutines and channels.

I have a loop where I'm doing some work (building some json files), and I want to open a new thread for each iteration, but at the end I want to wait for each thread to be done in order to continue on main thread working with these json files:

```
for item := range *programmes {
    go func() {
        do something
        operationDone <- true
    }()
}
```

There is a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `sync.WaitGroup`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for

Comment: Go doesn't give you the option of opening threads.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for item := range *programmes {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        do something
        wg.Done()
    }(&wg)
}
wg.Wait()
```